# What happens to threads when I dont explicitly call the join method?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I need to make some network calls for data in my program. I intend to call them in parallel but  not all of them need to complete.

What i have right now is

```
thread1 = makeNetworkCallThread()    
thread1.start()

thread2 = makeLongerNetworkCallThread()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
foo = thread1.getData()

thread2.join()
if conditionOn(foo):
    foo = thread2.getData()

# continue with code
```

the problem with this is that even if the shorter network call succeeded, I need to wait for the time it takes for the longer network call to complete

What will happen if I move the thread2.join() inside the if statement? The join method might never get called. Will that cause some problems with stale threads etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thread2` will still continue to run (subject to the caveats of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), but since it is a network call that's probably not a concern) whether `join` is called or not.  The difference is whether the main context waits for the thread to end before going on to do other things - if you're able to continue processing without that longer network call completing, then there should be no issues.

Do keep in mind that the program will not actually end (the interpreter will not exit) until all threads have been completed.  Depending on the latency of this long network call to the run time of the rest of your program (in the event you don't wait), it might appear that the program reaches its end but doesn't actually exit until the network call wraps up.  Consider this silly example:

```
# Python 2.7
import threading
import time
import logging

def wasteTime(sec):
  logging.info('Thread to waste %d seconds started' % sec)
  time.sleep(sec)
  logging.info('Thread to waste %d seconds ended' % sec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

  t1 = threading.Thread(target=wasteTime, args=(2,))
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=wasteTime, args=(10,))

  t1.start()
  t2.start()

  t1.join()
  logging.info('Main context done')
```

This is the logging output:

```
$ time python test.py
2015-01-15 09:32:12,239 Thread to waste 2 seconds started
2015-01-15 09:32:12,239 Thread to waste 10 seconds started
2015-01-15 09:32:14,240 Thread to waste 2 seconds ended
2015-01-15 09:32:14,241 Main context done
2015-01-15 09:32:22,240 Thread to waste 10 seconds ended

real    0m10.026s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Note that although the main context reached its end after 2 seconds (the amount of time it took for `thread1` to complete), the program doesn't completely exit until `thread2` is completed (ten seconds after start of execution).  In situations like this (particularly if the output is being logged as such), it's my opinion that it is better to explicitly call `join` at some point and explicitly identify in your logs that this is what the program is doing so that it doesn't look to the user/operator like it has hung.  For my silly example, that might look like adding lines like this to the end of the main context:

```
logging.info('Waiting for thread 2 to complete')
t2.join()
```

Which will generate somewhat less mysterious log output:

```
$ time python test.py
2015-01-15 09:39:18,979 Thread to waste 2 seconds started
2015-01-15 09:39:18,979 Thread to waste 10 seconds started
2015-01-15 09:39:20,980 Thread to waste 2 seconds ended
2015-01-15 09:39:20,980 Main context done
2015-01-15 09:39:20,980 Waiting for thread 2 to complete
2015-01-15 09:39:28,980 Thread to waste 10 seconds ended

real    0m10.027s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a network call and I am sure it will complete or timeout soon. No danger of the thread going on forever. Was only worried about any unexpected behaviour when a thread ends after its parent had already ended